# Seguridad en conexión a base de datos externa

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Si te conectas a una página web con el protocolo http esta no es segura por que el tráfico entre el cliente y el servidor no va cifrado.

Si este servidor emplea el protocolo https se considera seguro. Es decir la información que envió del formulario al servidor va cifrada.

Pero que sucede si el servidor web es https, pero la base de datos (Mysql o Sqlserver) está en otro servidor.

**¿La información que se transfiere entre un servidor web y un servidor de base de datos, ambos en maquinas diferentes, qué seguridad tiene?**

Comment: Http generalmente es puerto 80 , https 443 , puerto MySQL es 3306.. conclusión da igual si usa http(s) total entra por otro puerto

Comment: Lo que puedes mejorar en cuanto a seguridad es definir un usuario en tu base de datos que acceda por la IP de servidor , igual si quieres respuesta de este tipo deberás cambiar la pregunta porque hablar de seguridad en servidores es muy amplia

Comment: Entiendo que es muy amplio el asunto, pero espero una respuesta, bastante sencilla, por ejemplo que me digan que al momento de establecer la conexion con mysql o X SGBD la informacion viaja cifrada con x algoritmo y por lo tanto, no se puede dar un sniffing, pero descnozco el asunto, porque las consultas al servidor viajan por la red al fin y al cabo

Comment: Sencillo solo deja habilitado el puerto 3306 al servidor de base de datos y que se.concete tu servidor http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Si revisamos la documentación de Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encrypted-connections.html), podemos ver lo siguiente:

### Usando conexiones encriptadas con MySQL

MySQL admite conexiones encriptadas entre clientes y el servidor utilizando el protocolo [TLS (Transport Layer Security)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). A veces se hace referencia a TLS como [SSL (Secure Sockets Layer)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), pero MySQL no utiliza realmente el protocolo SSL para las conexiones encriptadas porque su encriptación es débil.(consulte la Sección 6.4.6, "[Cifrados y protocolos de conexión cifrados](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html)").

MySQL también se puede compilar para soporte de conexión encriptada usando [OpenSSL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) o [wolfSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WolfSSL).

Por defecto, los MySQL intentan conectarse usando encriptación si el servidor admite conexiones encriptadas, recurriendo a una conexión no encriptada solo si no se puede establecer una conexión encriptada.

MySQL realiza el cifrado por cada conexión, y el uso del cifrado para un usuario dado puede ser opcional u obligatorio. Esto le permite elegir una conexión cifrada o no cifrada de acuerdo con los requisitos de las aplicaciones individuales.

Las conexiones encriptadas se pueden usar también entre los servidores de replicación maestro y esclavo.

---

Para SQL Server puede revisar la documentacion [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Esta es como la respuesta que buscaba, aunque quedo con algunas dudas, pero has dejado un link interesante, gracias por tu aporte, en resumen podemos habilitar ssl en el servidor mysql, y supongo que sqlserver y otros sgbd tienen algo similar.

Comment: @AquilesPerez Me alegro que te ayudara. Aun que no entiendo por que alguien me votó negativo. En fin. Un saludo.

Comment: Si lo mismo me preguntaba @Xerif vi que tenia voto negativo, pero con el enlace que me diste, aclaré algunas dudas y vi que con pdo puedes especificar que la conexion usa SSL, para conectarte, Osea que las conexiones normales que hago sin SSL no son del todo seguras

Answer (score 0):

No hay ninguna seguridad intrínseca entre el servidor web y el servidor de BD. La arquitectura de la seguridad ya depende de la implementación, por ejemplo puedes hacer que la información viaje siempre encriptada y se desencripte en el destino.

En general si lo que quieres transmitir es el password por ejemplo, este nunca deberá estar en texto claro, ni siquiera en la base de datos, para esto puedes usar algún algoritmo de encriptación o también un algoritmo para generar hash de 1 solo sentido.

Comment: ummm quizá deba buscar en la documentacion oficial del sgbd, pero no se como formular la busqueda, no se si al establecer la conexion ya tienes alguna seguridad, porque en sql server creo que hay un parametro persistSecurity

Comment: @AquilesPerez ya te respondí de nuevo checale

Comment: Decir que que no existe ninguna seguridad entre un servidor web y un servidor de bd, es una falacia. Una cosa son los datos en si y otra muy diferente la comunicación entres servidores. Es igual o mas importante la seguridad en la comunicacion entre servidores, como los datos que se comunican.